# Что такое время простоя при использовании режима обслуживания Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Альтернативы режиму обслуживания
Поскольку для режима обслуживания требуется, чтобы у вашего приложения было несколько секунд простоя, рассмотрите альтернативы, такие как Laravel Vapor и Envoyer, для выполнения развертывания с нулевым временем простоя с Laravel.
Что здесь означает время простоя? Где и почему оно происходит? Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предполагаю, что в данном контексте говорится о времени простоя, когда приложение разворачивается на серверной инфраструктуре. Когда вы разворачиваете новый релиз на prodaction-сервере, то в определенный момент ваш сервис перестает отвечать на запросы пользователей, потому что старая версия уже отключена, а новая еще не развернута до конца, это и называется временем простоя. Указанные вами выше продукты, как раз призваны решить эту проблему в программной экосистеме Laravel

Comment: спасибо за помощь